# How to make site go into right link

Tags: javascript, html

I want to get a user input from input text, so I made form on html file:

```
<form class="inputform">
  <input type="text" id="getinput" autocomplete="off">
  <button id="hrefbutton" type="submit" onclick="hrefinput()">Search</button>
```

And I wrote Javascript on head of HTML file:

```
function hrefinput(){
  const inputs = document.getElementById('getinput').value;
  alert(inputs);
  window.location.href = "http://localhost/index/" + inputs;
}
```

And, everytime I test this code, I succesfully get alert with my inputs on, but the site would only goto "`http://localhost/index/?`"
I've searched for this but i cant find this kind of issues on my internet. Someone help me how to successfully go into "`https://localhost/index/<inputs>`". Thank you,

Comment: What value are you exactly passing into the input?

Comment: Hm it worked well for what reason do you have the form when you read the input at button click with onclick event?

Comment: Could you try to change type from `submit` to `button` ? `<button type="button">`

Comment: sorry for late reply, I got help from Erling T but still thank you for trying to help me as well! I'll try changing type to button later thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow

The problem you are facing is due to HTML forms default behavior, where it sends the form data by navigating to a specific `action` URL. As you didn't specify the `action` property on the form element your browser didn't know where to navigate. That apparently sent you to `/?`.

So how do you avoid this default behavior? It's pretty easy. You just call the `preventDefault` function on the `submit` event. Just make sure you pass the event to your `hrefinput` function like so:

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
  <form class="inputform" onsubmit="hrefinput(event)">
    <input type="text" id="getinput" autocomplete="off">
    <button id="hrefbutton" type="submit">Search</button>
  </form>

  <script>
  function hrefinput(event){
    event.preventDefault()
    const inputs = document.getElementById('getinput').value;
    alert(inputs);
    window.location.href = "http://localhost/index/" + inputs;
  }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Notice:

- I moved your function from `onclick` on the button to the form element as it's more proper